# collect2 error ld returned 1 exit status c program with function "wait"

Tags: gcc, makefile, wait

I'm trying to make a simple c program by utility make in terminal it shows this:

```
root@alireza:~/Documents/gnuc++/3/wait# make
gcc wait.o -o wait
/usr/bin/ld: cannot open output file wait: Is a directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
root@alireza:~/Documents/gnuc++/3/wait# gcc -o wait wait.c
/usr/bin/ld: cannot open output file wait: Is a directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
root@alireza:~/Documents/gnuc++/3/wait#
```

As shown above, I manually compiled the `wait.c` file, but it was an error again  (Whether gcc or g++).  :(

I don't know if it is compiler problem or I am doing it the wrong way.

I am using Kdevelop IDE and it worked.

> wait.c file

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>
 #include<sys/wait.h>
 #include<unistd.h>  
 int main() {
     pid_t cpid;
     if (fork()== 0)
         exit(0);           /* terminate child */
     else
         cpid = wait(NULL); /* reaping parent */
     printf("Parent pid = %d\n", getpid());
     printf("Child pid = %d\n", cpid);

     return 0;
}
```

and

> Makefile

```
 cc=gcc

 all: wait.o 
     $(cc) wait.o -o wait

 wait.o:
     $(cc) -c wait.c -o wait.o

 clean:
     rm -rf *.o wait    clear
```

**What should I do to work with a make or manually compile?**

Any help and tips on this are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you have a folder called "wait" in your output directory, try to rename your output to wait.out .

Comment: Okay, it worked. thank you.
Can I ask what was the cause?

Comment: As written in the error message: `/usr/bin/ld: cannot open output file wait: Is a directory`, the outputname _wait_ you chose is a *directory* in your output folder.